# Get elements from selenium webdriver one by one

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I have written a python script to automate and copy links in a webpage using selenium, but when there are large number of links, only a part of the links are obtained and rest are truncated. Is there a way to get the links one by one or increase the capacity of "list" item in python?

```
while(last==True):
    prevlen=aftlen
    brow.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);var lenOfPage=document.body.scrollHeight;")
    time.sleep(10)
    aftlen=len(brow.find_elements_by_class_name("answer_permalink"))
    print(aftlen)
    if(prevlen == aftlen):
            n=n+1
    if(n==10):
            last=False
            print("Scrolling completed")
filename='links.txt'
links=brow.find_elements_by_class_name("answer_permalink") #problem lies here all links are taken into list at once
outputfile=open(filename,mode='w')
print("writing to file")
for link in links:
        item=link.get_attribute("href")
        outputfile.write("%s\n" %item)
```

For example, I had 550 items webpage but only 496 links were fetched by webdriver into the list.

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?